# For what reasons is a MOSFET with a square wave at its gate outputting an irregular signal?

Tags: mosfet, switching

I am switching an IRFP250M with a square wave. Its output should be a sqquare wave too, but this is what i'm getting:

Measurements at 255kHz:
[image: oscilloscope output]

Measurements at 200kHz:
[image: oscilloscope output]

The first waveform is the gate signal and the second one the drain signal with a dummy 1k resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYtXXs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thank you,

Riccardo

Comment: Please tell us what each trace represents. If (2) should be a square wave maybe you have it set to AC-coupled. 48MHz is an extremely low sample rate for that waveform. A 'real' oscilloscope would sampling at more like 1Gs/s.

Comment: COuld be anything without a schematic............

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. There is nothing wrong with the sample rate at 48 MHz. If you set the sample rate to Gs/s then with you'd see only a small portion of the waveform! It depends on the length of the capture buffer of course, but most oscilloscopes have quite limited data buffers.

Comment: You have barely enough input signal to turn on the IRFP250M (VGS(th) is min 2 V), you need to be driving it with more than 4 V peak to ensure it is fully turned on.

Comment: @JackCreasey Without the resistor it's being driven at 13V peak, which should be more than enough to turn it on completely.

Comment: So which is it ...with or without the resistor. Your image shows a 2 V drive waveform.

Comment: His image shows a 12-odd V waveform on Ch1. It's 10V/div and the square wave's taller than 1 div.

Comment: @JackCreasey The 2V waveform is CH2, which is the drain waveform. CH1 is the gate waveform and that has a peak of 13V whithout resistor and 12.5 with the gate resistor.

Comment: Just to rule out daft mistakes, any chance you've got a divide-by-10 probe on Ch1 and it's actually at 1.2 V? Put a multimeter across the Ch1 measurement points and see if it reads 6..7 V. Sanity check, take you 20 secs.

Comment: @TonyM Just measured, 6.47V across those two points.

Comment: My bad....   It is strange the device does not saturate. Connect the gate directly to +12 and to ground and ensure it turns on and off fully.

Comment: what's the clock rate 250 kHz? looks like RC time constant with large drain capacitance.

Comment: @sstobbe the gate frequency is 255kHz

Comment: @JackCreasey the fet is turning on and off just fine, just checked.

Comment: Drop the frequency to 25 kHz just to prove that's the issue, then you can proceed with solutions.

Comment: I'd suggest the output impedance of your drive circuit is too high. Your square wave should drive it from off to saturation cleanly and that appears not to be the case.

Comment: Did you invert channel 2 for the 200kHz plot?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes i did, the probe is on the GND side

Comment: Thanks for checking. Your FET's gate capacitance is 2159 pF, call it 2.2 nF. So inputs RC looks OK for timing though you're asking a lot of your drive. (a) Try dropping the gate drive voltage. (b) Try dropping your load resistance to 100 R, see if that makes any difference. I'm wondering what your circuit looks like, dunno if its a PCB or a long-wired lash-up, but let's see if a stronger drive current affects the spikes. Only take 2 mins, please post a trace of that. (c) What's your drive circuit, exactly? (d) Have you/can you try another FET?

Comment: @TonyM I replaced the dummy resistor with a 100Ohm resistor as you suggested and the output is looking way better: http://imgur.com/a/sehNW - The circuit is on a breadboard with a mess of wires. This is my circuit. I made some minor changes but the main stuff is still there: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307575/why-are-mosfets-switching-at-a-different-speed-than-the-one-they-are-being-drive

Comment: Oh good and looks like @SpehroPefhany had the right idea, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have two (or more) problems. First your output signal appears to be AC coupled so you are not seeing the DC level. But what you would expect in that case would be two spikes, one at each edge of the square wave in opposite directions.

Which brings us to the second problem. You are driving a [rather beefy MOSFET](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfp250mpbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015356287bc71fda) with a rather high value pullup resistor at a relatively high frequency. In addition to that your probe with whatever it is connected to is adding even more capacitance. So you see a sharp negative-going spike when the MOSFET turns 'on' but a slow ramp when it turns off.

The capacitance appears still to be quite large compared to the 315pF typical output capacitance of the MOSFET. Check the probe capacitance and use a x10 setting if possible. Also check that the resistor is actually 1K and not 10K (sometimes color codes can be confusing, especially if you mix 4 and 5 band resistors).

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be a capacitance issue.

Comment: Using a ferrite bead on the gate instead of a plain resistor can sometimes help with issues caused by ringing